# Collapse Stashes by default in Team Explorer - Changes

Tags: visual-studio

Every time when I open `Team Explorer - Changes` the `Stashes` section is opened and I'm not able to see all changed files, so I have to collapse the `Stashes` section.

Is it possible to set the `Stashes` section **collapsed** by **default**?

Visual Studio 2019 version: 16.3.0

[image]

Comment: Version 16.5.5 still not able to collapse by default